# Best way to get back data from PHP script after POST from Android App

Tags: php, android, security, post, echo

Hi guys I am trying to set up a Login form in my android App.

This is how things actually work: the user enters his username and password in two `EditText`, this informations are sended to a PHP script through POST, the PHP scrip queries the DB and returns 1 (CORRECT USER AND PASS!) or 0 (NOT CONNECTED, INVALID USER OR PASS).

The "problem" is that now I'm doing it this way:

```
<?php
  /../
  if(conneted == true){
     echo 1;
  } else {
     echo 2; 
  }
?>
```

In my android App I obtain the `HttpResponse` that contains 1 or 0.

But is this safe? Using `echo` is the best way to obtain an answer from the script?

Thank you!
Marco

Comment: What do you mean `safe`?

Comment: Well, it's the simplest and safest way over HTTP :)

Comment: @OZ - I'm not expert about PHP and I don't know if using echo I provide some easy hacking way to access the app without being registered.
@Michael J.V. It's all I need to hear, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this you may want to use the HTTP status: 200 for success and a **403 Forbidden** for the NOT_CONNECTED, INVALID USER or INVALID PASS states. You can then use the body of the message for the explanation (if you care to provide an explanation: you may not want to for security reasons).

EDIT: so

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 403 Forbidden");
```

if the authentication failed and

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 200 OK");
```

if the authentication succeeded.